# How to derive a sequence number in paxos

Tags: distributed-system, paxos

In paxos, every proposer independently generates a sequence number for its proposal. So let's say a proposer keeps on generating higher numbered sequence number. Won't this proposer because he is generating higher sequence number nullify other proposers proposals? i.e. is there a possibility in paxos where one proposer always dominate?

Answer (score 4):

That would be a problem if your proposer was [acting badly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance#Byzantine_Generals'_Problem). In practice the proposers follow a simple protocol for choosing sequencers.

For example, in one system I maintained a list of allowed proposers was replicated along with the data, so all proposers had a position `p`. A proposer would always choose its `i`th sequence number like this: `seqno(i, p) = i * len(proposers) + p`. Thus every proposer had a unique set of (interleaved) sequence numbers to choose from.